# Can we make [pbta] a synonym for [powered-by-the-apocalypse]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, game-systems

In many places online, people refer to all games derived from *Apocalypse World* as "PbtA", short for "Powered by the Apocalypse".

Could we make [pbta](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pbta) a synonym for our [powered-by-the-apocalypse](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powered-by-the-apocalypse) tag?

Comment: Looks like nitsua60 added it at Feb 14 at 13:37

Comment: @Bloodcinder, when I'm trying to tag a question, typing "pbta" doesn't bring anything up.

Comment: My apologies. It's pending. I read the listing wrong.

Comment: @Bloodcinder, where do you go to see this?

Comment: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

Comment: I don't know how many upvotes over how many answers you need to be able to vote for a synonym, but most likely SevenSidedDie & Zachiel are the only users even close to having enough.

Comment: I concur. This voting threshold is bonkers. If I can propose a synonym, why can't I vote for one? This one in particular deserves a mod override RIGHT EFFING NOW